# I want to ask a question about javascript image src

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<img src="../1.jpg" alt="" id="change-image">
<button id= "press-to-change">Press</button>

let count = 0;
let arr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg"]
document.getElementById("press-to-change").addEventListener("click", function(){
count++;
document.getElementById("change-image").src = "../" + arr[count]
```

So we have an HTML with an image and a button and in JS we have an array with images and we want to change the src of the image when we press the button(this is only a part of the code)
The above code works fine but i have a question why with:
`document.getElementById("change-image").src = "../" + arr[count]` code works fine but with `` document.getElementById("change-image").src = `url('../${arrImage[count]}')` ``  code doesn't work.
For example this next code from another project works perfectly `` imageContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url('../${arrImage[count]}')` ``

Comment: where is defined the `url`function?

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` is a for `style` of an element and uses css format.

`src` is for the actual source of the image element and requires a valid path only

Answer (score 1):

With images, you use or assign to the `src` property *only* for `<img>` elements.

If you want to set the background image of an arbitrary (but non-`<img>`) element, you need to use different syntax: you have to assign to the `style.backgroundImage` property, and you have to surround the URL you're setting with `url(...)`

The rendered HTML markup looks like this:

```
<img src="foobar.png">
<div style="background-image: url('foobar.png');"></div>
```

They're not interchangeable. With the `background-image` property, you need to always use `url(...)`. With the `src` attribute, you need to never use `url(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The text: `url(image.jpg)` is syntax only used in CSS.

That’s why it works for `backgroundImage` but not `src`

An image will always need `src="path/to/image.jpg"` without `url()` surrounding it.